# Netty tcnative: error:10000070:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_PACKET_LENGTH

Tags: netty, boringssl

I use Netty `4.1.92.Final` with `netty-tcnative-boringssl-static` version `2.0.60.Final`. I get the below error **sometimes**  (Also, sometimes it's very frequent and CPU uses shoots up very high).

I am not able to figure out the root cause and any possible fix.

```
io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine$OpenSslHandshakeException: error:10000070:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_PACKET_LENGTH
```

Code:

```
SslProvider provider = SslProvider.isAlpnSupported(SslProvider.OPENSSL) ? SslProvider.OPENSSL : SslProvider.JDK;
logger.info("SSL provider: {}", provider);
sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(keyManagerFactory)
    .sslProvider(provider)
    .ciphers(cypherList)
    .applicationProtocolConfig(new ApplicationProtocolConfig(
        Protocol.ALPN,
        SelectorFailureBehavior.NO_ADVERTISE,
        SelectedListenerFailureBehavior.ACCEPT,
        ApplicationProtocolNames.HTTP_1_1
    ))
    .sessionCacheSize(SSL_SESSION_CACHE_SIZE) // 1800 -> 30 mins
    .sessionTimeout(SSL_SESSION_CACHE_TIMEOUT_SECOND) // 1024 * 100 -> 1000_00 sessions
    .build();
```

I am assuming it doesn't depend on the installed version of `openssl` on the linux server.

Any possible fix or way to debug the real reason?